# Invoke web service from android application using soap object

Tags: android, asp.net, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I wrote a class called callSoap that invokes a web service (asmx) called test , 
the web method called GetData take integer as parameter and return list of strings 
I defined 
 SOAP_ACTION 
OPERATION_NAME 
WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE
SOAP_ADDRESS
of my web service but the connection failed it and it did not return data 
have anyone an idea about this ?

```
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetData";

public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetData"; 

public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:8216/test.asmx";

public String Call(int id)
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("id");
    pi.setValue(id);
    pi.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);


 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 envelope.dotNet = true;

 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

 HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
 Object response=null;
try
{
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    response = envelope.getResponse();
    }
catch (Exception exception)
{
response=exception.toString();
}

return response.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8216/test.asmx` should be `http://10.0.2.2:8216/test.asmx`

Comment: I changed it, socket failed !

Comment: I had an exception in calling web service

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: You have to do internet operations on a thread. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html